# jQuery Toggle div class on load depending on the content height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, toggle

I have a **dynamic content loaded** on my template. The default div background-color is yellow, but when teh content is longer than 300px div toggles or appends the class that wil change the background-color to red. Below is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css" media="all">
.short {background-color:yellow;padding:30px; width:200px;}
.long {background-color:red;padding:30px;width:200px;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="short">div content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is your dynamic content loaded? Is there somewhere we can hook into that we can be sure it is after the content has finished dynamically loading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".short").each(function(){
    if($(this).height() > 300){
      $(this).removeClass("short").addClass("long");
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Does this content gets rendered from server or you load it from client side using AJAX?

Comment: from the server:
    <body>
    <div class="short"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"></div>
    <div class="short"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x310"></div>
    </body>

they both come out yellow - can't paste the whole the code not enough space

Comment: I see that you have multiple divs with class 'short'. Do you want the combined height of those divs to be greater than 300?

Comment: it's OK I made a mistake, works perfectly.

the original code was fine:

    $(document).ready(function(){
        if($(".short").height() > 300){
    $(".short").removeClass("short").addClass("long");
    }

});

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.short, div.long').each(function(){
  if($(this).height() > 300) {
    $(this).removeClass('short').addClass('long');
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('long').addClass('short');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you changed your html to look something like this:

```
<div id="messageDiv" class="short">div content</div>
```

Then you could use some code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var $messageDiv = $("#messageDiv");
   if($messageDiv.height() > 300) {
     $messageDiv.toggleClass("long short");
   }
});
```

But thats only a rough idea because it not clear how you are dynamically loading content and how we can know when to test the height.